# PHP domDocument parsing with HTML Table ( PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object)

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have an isolated problem with DOMDocument Where the following message appears in the log file:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object

The isolated problem code looks like this:

```
$data = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><table id=\"rang-table\"><thead> <tr> <th data-priority=\"2\">Rang</th> <th data-priority=\"1\">Name</th> <th data-priority=\"3\">Punkte</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr><td>1</td><td>Nadja F.</td><td align=\"right\">-9.44</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Karsten G.</td><td align=\"right\">-2.71</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Bjoern K.</td><td align=\"right\">-1.97</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Stefanie A.</td><td align=\"right\">-0.74</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Christian S.</td><td align=\"right\">1.94</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>Rene H.</td><td align=\"right\">2.68</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>Boris H.</td><td align=\"right\">10.24</td></tr> </tbody> </table></body></html>";

$dom = new domDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$betreffzeile = "";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $betreffzeile.=$cols[2];
}  
echo $betreffzeile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array returned by `getElementsByTagName` is zero-indexed, meaning that in this case, `$tables[1]` does not exist (you only have one table in the HTML, and that table is referred to as `$tables[0]`) so you need to change the definition of `$rows` to this:

`$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');`

You also have an error in the loop; you can't refer to a DOMNodelist with an index like you are. You'd need to change the assignment of `$betreffzeile` to this: `$betreffzeile.=$cols->item(2)->nodeValue;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out the obvious, the indices starts at zero, right now you only have that single table which means it'll fall under `0`:

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); // returns DOMNodeList
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); // point to first element index 0
```

It seems you're trying to get the third `<td>` values inside the `<tbody>` why not point to it directly:

```
$tbody = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');
$rows = $tbody->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$betreffzeile = "";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $betreffzeile .= $cols->item(2)->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}  
echo $betreffzeile;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cQO62E)